# Работа с bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

Есть локальный git-репозиторий, есть аккаунт в bitbucket, на нём есть приватный git-репозиторий. Как выложить локальный репозиторий в bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

Заходите в папку Projects и там создавайте Репозиторий, нажимая на кнопку "+".